# How to shift all the canvas actions in one function by another function selectively

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

**Consider the following example.**

```
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
function draw(){
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,10,10);
};
function render(){
    var coordinates = {x:100,y:200};
    draw();
};
```

**Question**

This would simply enough draw a black rectangle 10 pixels from the top and left side of the canvas. However how can I instruct the program to shift everything drawn in the function `draw` by the values in `coordinates`?

**My Current Ideas and Why They Wont Work**

1. Use the translate method by saving and restoring the context. This is unreliable because the draw function may include save and restores as well and they would conflict.
2. Draw everything in the `draw` function on a separate canvas and then draw that canvas using `drawImage` onto the desired canvas with the desired translations. Example: `draImage(canvas,coordinates.x,coordinates.y);`. This fails because since the `draw` function was created in the same scope as `ctx`, even if `ctx` is redefined in `render` it will still draw using the original `ctx`.
3. Turn the function into a string and use regex to shift all drawing values... Highly impractical.
4. Use pixel manipulation... This would move things outside of the draw function as well, thus it must be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your original idea of multiple save/restore.

Canvas states are pushed on a stack with every context.save(), and popped with every context.restore().

Therefore you should have no problem "nesting" save/restore's.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable outside the scope of the functions

```
var coordinates;

var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
function draw(){
//use the values
    ctx.fillRect(coordinates.x,coordinates.y,10,10);
};
function render(){
//set the values
    coordinates = {x:100,y:200};
    draw();
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option because the draw function is user submitted, and i would like everything they instruct in that function to be shifted however the program needs it to be.